# Push the csv file data to google sheets

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets, python-requests, gspread

I need to load the csv file data to google sheets. I used gspread to import csv to google sheets but it can only work with personal drive but not the team drive.

Here is my next approach.

I tried to put the contents of csv file to list and then update the cells of google sheets from the list and got 429 error. How can I avoid this error?

```
row = 1
column = 1
Fi = []
Fi = open("data.csv",'r')
for value in Fi:
    items = value.strip().split(',')
    for item in items:
        sheet.update_cell(row, column, item)
        column +=1
    row +=1
    column = 1

sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
Fi.close()
```

This is the error that I got

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'Write requests per user per 100 seconds' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:226307199654'.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/<proj_num>/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: error shows as you call gsheet api too often, maybe you can add time sleep and lower the api call rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be solved if you track write requests and only send requests as per the quota allocated per 100secs. And using sleep function to wait for the quota to reset after another 100sec.

```
import time

row = 1
column = 1
requestCount = 0
writeQuota = 100 #This is the limit for write request per 100 seconds
Fi = []
Fi = open("data.csv",'r')
for value in Fi:
    items = value.strip().split(',')
    for item in items:
        if(requestCount == writeQuota):
            time.sleep(100)
            requestCount = 0
        sheet.update_cell(row, column, item)
        requestCount += 1
        column += 1
    row += 1
    column = 1

sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
Fi.close()
```

Try and check if something like this works. Also play around with sleep time and double check your write quota.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sleep function each time request is done. as error above you need to wait more than 100 seconds after each write request is done.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling to often to `update_cells`.
According to `gspread` documentation [here](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#updating-cells)

you can do it in batch:

> ```
> cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:C7')
> for cell in cell_list:
>     cell.value = 'O_o'
> # Update in batch
> worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
> ```

so, appearing that your solution is:

```
Fi = []
Fi = open("data.csv",'r')
items=[]
for value in Fi:
    for item in value.strip().split(','):
        items.append(item)

cell_list = worksheet.range('A1:ENDRANGE') # according to csv
for cell, item in cell_list, items:
    cell.value=item

sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
Fi.close()
```

I didn't test it.